# Github Actions Build - Push to ECR on Multiple Folders

Tags: python, .net, docker, automation, github-actions

I have below folder structure in my GitHub repository.

```
docker
  serverless
    dotnet
      2.1
        Dockerfile
      3.1
        Dockerfile
    python
      3.8
        Dockerfile
```

Now I have automate the build and push to ECR using github-actions.

Is it possible using github-actions to traverse through each folder and trigger build?

I want if changes are pushed to

- 2.1 `Dockerfile` the image should always be tagged with 2.1 tag and pushed to ECR

and

- If changes are in 3.1 `Dockerfile` it should always be tagged with 3.1 and pushed to ECR.

Any ideas on how to achieve this using github-actions?

Comment: I posted an answer describing how to trigger workflows based on path. Is this sufficient, or do you need some guidance on how to build and push Docker images to a container registry?

Comment: @jidicula the repo is monorepo, so below CI steps can be in one workflow file?

Comment: You can have more than 1 workflow in a repo. The decision to split Actions into workflows is largely based on how they're triggered - since your desired outcome depends on 2 different triggers, imo you need 2 workflow files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`on.<push|pull_request>.paths`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onpushpull_requestpaths) trigger. When `paths` is specified, any push that changes anything in `paths` will trigger the workflow. You can use this trigger in 2 workflows (one for each version):

```yaml
# Trigger build for 2.1
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - 'main'
    paths:
      - docker/serverless/dotnet/2.1/Dockerfile

name: Build and push 2.1 image

jobs:
  buildpush:
    runs-on: 'ubuntu-latest'
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      # build and push steps go here
```

```yaml
# Trigger build for 3.1
on:
  push:
    branches:
     - 'main'
    paths:
     - docker/serverless/dotnet/3.1/Dockerfile

name: Build and push 3.1 image

jobs:
  buildpush:
    runs-on: 'ubuntu-latest'
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      # build and push steps go here
```